# Is it possible to use sql parameterized query to insert into encrypted columns with symmetric encryption

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I am working on **database encryption**, i.e. **cell based symmetric encryption** in SQL server 2008 Express.
But the problem is that the parameterized queries for insertion are not working. Help me please . . .

Edit:

I am using the following query as Example:

```
foreach (var list in from DataRow row in dataTable.Rows select new ArrayList
                           {
                                 String.Format("@var1, {0}", row["Column1"]), 
                                 String.Format("@var2, {0}", row["Column2"]),
                                 String.Format("@var3, {0}", row["Column3"])
                           })
    {
         var query = String.Format(@"OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY {0} DECRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE {1} 
                     INSERT INTO TableA (Column1, Column2, Column3) VALUES (@ENCRYPTBYKEY(KEY_GUID('symKey'), '{2}'), ENCRYPTBYKEY(KEY_GUID('symKey'), '{3}'), ENCRYPTBYKEY(KEY_GUID('symKey'), '{4}'))", symKey, symCer, "@var1", "@var2", "@var3");
         con.Execute.ExecuteParameterizedQuery(query, list);
    }

public string ExecuteParameterizedQuery(string query, ArrayList parametersList)
{
      errorFlag = Connect(un, pasw, 3);
      if ((String.CompareOrdinal(errorFlag, "Open") == 0))
      {
          var myTran = myConnection.BeginTransaction();
          cmd = new SqlCommand(query, myConnection) { Transaction = myTran };
          for (var i = 0; i < parametersList.Count; i++)
          {
              var split = parametersList[i].ToString().Split(',');
              cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(split[0], split[1]);
          }
          try
          {
              cmd.CommandText = query;
              cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
              myTran.Commit();
              errorFlag = string.Empty;
          }
          catch (Exception e)
          {
              errorFlag = e.Message;
          }
          finally
          {
              myConnection.Close();
              myConnection.Dispose();
          }
          return errorFlag;
      }
      myConnection.Close();
      myConnection.Dispose();
      return errorFlag;
  }
```

EDIT 2:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ng_encryptString
(
    @PlaneText VARCHAR(500), @SipherText VARBINARY(2000) OUT
)
AS
BEGIN
OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY symKey DECRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE SymCert 
SELECT ENCRYPTBYKEY(KEY_GUID('SymKey'), @PlaneText)
END
```

Comment: Could you mention an example to explain it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here what I would suggest is,

1. CREATE a procedure with

   ```
   INSERT INTO TableA (Column1, Column2, Column3) VALUES(@val1,@val2,@val3)
   ```
2. Now create a `encryptThestring(string val)` function in C# and it should return you the encrypted values of the given normal input value.
3. Finally call the procedure in C# and pass the parameter as

   ```
   encryptThestring(string val1)
   encryptThestring(string val2)
   encryptThestring(string val3)
   ```

This is the C#.net function

```
public string EncryptString(string val)
            {
                SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection("conn_string");
                sqlconn.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
                cmd.Connection = sqlconn;

                cmd.CommandText = "ng_encryptString"; // This is the sproc which will encrypt the string
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                SqlParameter param1 = cmd.Parameters.Add("inpuStr", SqlDbType.VarChar, 500);
                param1.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;

                SqlParameter param3 = cmd.Parameters.Add("@encryptedStr", SqlDbType.VarChar, 2000);
                param3.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

                param1.Value = val;

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                sqlconn.Close();
                return (string)param3.Value;

            }
```

sproc ng_encryptString

```
CREATE Procedure [dbo].[ng_encryptString]  
@string varchar(255),  
@encryptedStr varbinary(2000)  OUTPUT  

As  
Begin  


Declare @res varbinary(2000)  

IF NOT EXISTS(select * from sys.symmetric_keys where name='##MS_DatabaseMasterKey##')  
CREATE MASTER KEY ENCRYPTION  
BY PASSWORD = 'yourpassword'  


IF NOT EXISTS(select * from sys.certificates where name='EncryptTestCert')  
CREATE CERTIFICATE EncryptTestCert  
WITH SUBJECT = 'yoursubject'  

IF NOT EXISTS(select * from sys.symmetric_keys where name='TestTableKey')   
CREATE SYMMETRIC KEY TestTableKey  
WITH ALGORITHM = TRIPLE_DES ENCRYPTION  
BY CERTIFICATE EncryptTestCert  

OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY TestTableKey DECRYPTION  
BY CERTIFICATE EncryptTestCert  


SELECT @encryptedStr=ENCRYPTBYKEY(KEY_GUID('TestTableKey'),@string)  

end
```

Comment: I do not want to encrypt any string using C#.

Comment: No you dont have to encrypt using C#,just call the sql statements in that function and get back the requied encrypted string.

Comment: In above EncryptString Method, could not found the stored procedure 'ng_encryptString'

Comment: That proc you have to write based on your encryption key ..!!

Comment: I have created a procedure but gives an error, can you help me?

Comment: The error is: Implicit conversion from data type varchar to varbinary is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query

Comment: You can view the procedure in EDIT2 block of this question.

Comment: Check the sproc in the answer above.I have written the sproc

Comment: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Byte[]' to type 'System.String'. And also comes while inserting in parameterized query. in C#

Implicit conversion from data type nvarchar to varbinary is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query. in sql server

Comment: Now check the sproc.I have changed the return variable datatype to varbinary

Comment: Procedure is working fine and returns byte[] but when I call it in parametrized query then while execution of insertion query, an error appears i-e: Implicit conversion from data type nvarchar to varbinary is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query.

Comment: The datatype of columns of my table is binary.

Comment: so cant you use the convert there?